# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized Error using jwt with asp.net core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

When to run the web api on the localhost without any problem

url: http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login

but when I publish the web api and run on the iis and windows server 2012 get this error when run login request:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

startup code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "test.com",
                    ValidAudience = "test.com",
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("alisFhgsFsjfsjfd@#asdsaczx123@asd23-"))
                };
            });
```

and request code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("test.com/api/sms/LoginToken");
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                String username = login.Mobile;
                String password = login.Password;
                String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

**The requset does not enter the action web api**
And other action run correctly

Comment: Check your server logs.. Do you have `app.UseAuthentication()` in your `Startup.Configure`?

Comment: @poke Yes I have `app.UseAuthentication()` and    `app.UseStaticFiles(); app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseMvc();  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`

Comment: @Ahmad Your server expects a request with `Authorization: Bearer <JWT-TOKEN-INSTEAD-OF-BASIC-AUTHENTICATION-USER&PASSWORD>`, however, your `Authorization` header of `httpWebRequest`  is `Authorization: Basic <base64(username:password)>`